# How do I detect in which page ajax_query_attachments_args is loaded?

Tags: ajax

I'm trying to hide attachments with a taxonomy. I want to hide them from Post page in wp-admin. I can't figure out how to detect the page I'm in from ajax_query_attachments_args. I tried to use pre_get_posts, but it doesn't seem to trigger ajax_query_attachments_args.

```
add_filter('ajax_query_attachments_args', 'hide_attachment_with_taxonomy', 50, 1);  

function hide_attachment_with_taxonomy( $query = array() ) {
        global $current_screen;

        if ( ! $current_screen ) {
            return $query; // It always return this value. $current_screen or get_current_screen() is always undefined
        }


        if($current_screen->post_type == 'post'){
          $query['tax_query'] = array(
            array(
              'taxonomy' => 'category',
              'operator' => 'NOT EXISTS'
            ),
          ); 

          return $query;
       }
}
```

Comment: You can try something like `$base = basename( wp_get_referer() ); if ( 'post.php' === substr( $base, 0, 8 ) ) { your code here }`

Comment: Yes, wp_get_referer() is the answer I was looking for. I'm now able to parse the "post" parameter from the url and get_post_type() to identify the post_type. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is wp_get_referer(). This function is working inside ajax_query_attachments_args. I can then use get_post_type with the post id from url parameters

```
$referer = parse_url(wp_get_referer());
parse_str($referer['query'], $params);

if (isset($params['post'])){
    $post_type = get_post_type($params['post']);
} else if (strpos($referer['path'], 'post-new.php') !== false && !isset($params['post_type'])){
    $post_type = 'post';
} else {
    $post_type = '';
}

if ( $post_type == 'post' ) {    
    $query['tax_query'] = array(
      array(
          'taxonomy' => 'category',
          'operator' => 'NOT EXISTS'
      ),
    ); 
}
```